# PHP Regex: Match section of string based on part of section

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to extract the age limitations from strings:

```
Example:
(Class 4) (0-110, 5yo+) 3m1f Good To Firm 18 fences
Return:
5yo+
```

Other examples would be 2yo, 3yo, 2-3yo, 4yo+, etc.

How do I match whole word if yo exists. I tried playing with `\b` but cannot get it to return the whole `5yo+` if yo is found :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, and should work for all of the examples you have given:

```
$str = '(Class 4) (0-110, 5yo+) 3m1f Good To Firm 18 fences';
if (preg_match('/[0-9-]+yo\\+?/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "Matched: $matches[0]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/.*(\b[0-9-]+yo\+?\b).*/\1/
```

is the regex you seem to be looking for

Comment: oh, i was trying to be a bit too clever :) thank you very much.

Comment: This regex will not match the text "2-3yo" and will replace a string containing it with "3yo".

Comment: @cdhowie you are right sorry overlooked that option, indeed i should add the - in the [0-9] part